# White pixels when resizing semi-transparent bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

Sometimes when I resize semi-transparent png's I get weird white pixels on shapes edges. This happens only with images that have shapes (not photos) and when  `InterpolationMode` is set to `HighQualityBicubic`. Does anyone know why this white pixels show? I get them only on some images.

This is the result I get:

[image]

This is the source file:

[image]

This is similar file, that does not cause that "white pixel" effect.

[image]

Drawing code is very simple:

```
Bitmap resize = new Bitmap(1024, 177, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resize))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Wave01, 0, 0, 1024, 177);
}
```

Please note, that I use `HighQualityBicubic` because the code is used for resizing various types of images including photos. Using `InterpolationMode.Default` seems to solve the problem, but then resizing some image types may produce worse results than `HighQualityBicubic`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772273/interpolationmode-highqualitybicubic-introducing-artefacts-on-edge-of-resized-im

Comment: @BrettWolfington - I think it's not the same. These are not semi transparent pixels and definitely are not on image edges. Solution for what you are referring is to use `ImageAttributes` with `WrapMode` set to `WrapMode.TileFlipXY`. But this affects only image borders.